# Draw and make line move on camera surfaceview change

Tags: android, camera, android-canvas

I want to implement an application where in I am drawing a line on the Android camera `SurfaceView`. However as I move my camera, the line should also move. At present the line is static and does not move along with the camera.

I am drawing the line using the Canvas `drawLine` method as follows

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawLine(50, 50, 50, 50, paint);

}
```

Can anyone suggest how to make line move everytime the surface view changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you detect if the camera is moving?

Its not that simple...

Something like this you would find in libraries for Augmented reality. These libs use the sensors (accelerometer, orientation etc...) to get readings on how the phone is oriented and how it rotates in 3d space. then with calculations you can adjust where the overlays are drawn on a surface. The concept is more general. it doesn't have to be a camera surface below that.

Try looking at something like this:
https://code.google.com/p/mixare/

Comment: so without using third party libraries like mixare, is this possible if i use only the native Android code

Comment: Yes, write your own code to do this. its not a trivial tasks however. I think mixare is more than you need. you can get parts the code out and adjust it for your needs.